# ItemVisibilityEventArgs Event not worked Properly for iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

ListView's "ItemAppearing" event seems only triggered on Android viewcell renderer but not on iOS.

I am Created a Custom Listview Renderer to display the all Values but it will not . Its Working in Android but not in iOS.

My Custom Code Below,

```
 public ICommand ItemAppearingCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ItemAppearingCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemAppearingCommandProperty, value); }
        }



private void OnItemAppearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ItemAppearingCommand != null)
            {
                ItemAppearingCommand?.Execute(e.Item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did it get into this method ?if yes,you could see if ItemAppearingCommand is null